# Obtain Open source code from Github with regular bug fixes

Tags: github, git-clone

I have cloned an open source code from Github public repository into my PC. I've customized the code a little to suit my requirement and pushed them it to my own private repository. Now if there is any fix or update provided from original source provider, how can I pull it into my private repository ?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you now have two remotes: original and your private, so you can see list of remotes:

```
$ git remote -v
```

Then fetch changes from original, I think it could be named "origin":

```
$ git fetch origin
```